# C++, VS2010: Avoid downloading MS redistrubutable package. Link statically?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Can VS2010 link EVERYTHING into exe file that is needed? Or should i put MS VS2010 files into installation package? I don't want user to think about downloading and installing something.

Comment: Have a look at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/10/12/how-to-redistribute-the-visual-c-libraries-with-your-application.aspx which shows how to distribute the shared libraries.

Comment: Yes, you can link everything statically

Comment: As long as you're not using `/clr`...

Answer (score 1):

Having tried to use static linkage for this reason in a large MFC project, using VS2010, I find that I still need to run the VS2010 SP1 redist package.  The software works to a large extent without it, but users see a fair number of additional random bugs that seem to miraculously disappear once the redist is installed.  I'm guessing it updates other windows components that the run-times are dependant on, but it is only a guess.  My advice is to include it with your installation.

Comment: Or maybe i should use MinGW (-;